# Showing the following subset of the dual space is compact

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-topology

Let $X$ be a real, normed space,and  $I$ a non-empty index set. Let $ \{x_i : i\in I\} \subset X$ and $\{ \alpha_i : i\in I\} \subset \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, $R > 0$. For $$ S := \{ f\in X^* : ||f||\leq R \text{ and } |f(x_i)|\leq \alpha_i \text{ for each }i\in I \},$$ I want to show, for arbitrary $x_0\in X$ that the set $$\{ f(x_0) : f\in S\}$$ is a closed and bounded interval on $\mathbb{R}$.

To do this, I tried to show $S$ is compact and convex as a subset of the continuous dual $X^*$, since then the result will follow by using Conway, Proposition V.7.9., which says that the image under a continuous affine map of a convex compact subest of a locally convex space is compact and convex.

I'm using Conway's definition for compactness, and trying to show compactness by showing each net in $S$ clusters, but I'm still stuggling with proofs regarding nets and I can't see how I should define the cluster point. I'm thus also unsure if this is the easiest way to go about this proof? [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4280953/prove-fx-0f-in-a-is-closed-interval-for-a-f-in-x-f-leq-beta-f) there is an alternative way of solving this, but this is slightly different.

Answer (score 2):

A special case of what you are trying to prove occurs whenever $\alpha_i=R\|x_i\|$ for each $i$, in which case $S$ is just the ball of radius $R$ in $X^*$.  Therefore, trying to directly prove $S$ is weak-* compact amounts to at least (re?)-proving Banach Alaoglu.

If you already have Banach Alaoglu then you may as well use it, as they do at the link, since $S$, as a closed subset of the ball, must then also be weak-* compact.

Otherwise, anything you do will at least reprove that theorem.